# How can I enable my server side console logs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux

I made some server middleware in api/index.js

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next){
    console.log(req);
    next();
};
```

And added this to my nuxt.config.js

```
serverMiddleware: [{path: 'stocks', handler: '~/api/index.js'}],
```

As explained in this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j-3RwvWZoaU tutorial. But I'm not seeing any server side logs in the terminal when I run npm run dev and follow the route. I used to see server side logs in the browsers console I think but with this project I am not. How can I see my server side logs I'm using `"nuxt": "^2.0.0",`

Answer (score 0):

I had to run it with npm run start. Now I see the messages in the terminal!